# Javascript - Every Array Has 'some' As A Key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I read on another post to use ('thing' in array) to determine if an array has a key.

```
var capitals = [];
if(!('California' in capitals))
    capitals['California'] = 'Sacramento';
alert("The capital is " + capitals['California']);
```

Having problems when trying to check keys using the word "some" though since it's an array method:

```
var arr = [];
var mykey = 'some';
if(mykey in arr)
    alert("the word 'some' is in the array, value: " + arr[mykey]);
```

the alert is: the word 'some' is in the array, value: function some() { [native code] }

I have not set anything to the array at the key 'some', but "in" returns a positive since it's a method.  Given that the word "some" is pretty common in English, how should I go about indexing words in an english sentence if "some" is a reserved key?

https://jsfiddle.net/fcmjL728/

Comment: Use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or an object without prototype (`Object.create(null)`), not an array.

Comment: [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is a method of Array.

Comment: The `in` operator doesn't check the values in an object, it checks the keys. Arrays only have integer keys and the functions in their prototype.

Comment: I'm not attempting to check the values in the object, I'm trying to check if a particular key exists.  I'm able to do arr['California'] = 'Sacramento' then I can do if('California' in arr) and it returns true.  However, if('some' in arr) also return true.  Is my premise of doing arr['California'] = 'Sacramento'; already a no-no?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an empty object for counting, because [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is a method of Array.

```js
var string = 'This is an example with some content and with some more words to count',
    count = Object.create(null); // a really empty object without prototypes from Object

string.split(' ').forEach(function (a) {
    var key = a.toLowerCase();
    count[key] = (count[key] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(count);
```